# How to get JSON object value from JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

I parse a data from 3rd party API call which is

```
"flows":[                          
    {
      "psy_num" : 3,
      "Age" : 25,
      "Results" : "You are smart enough to get into business" 
    }   
    ,
    {
      "psy_num" : 1,
      "Age" : 25,
      "Results" : "You are smart enough to get into business"
    }
    ,
    {
      "psy_num" : 3,
      "Age" : 28,
      "Results" : "You are smart enough to get into business"
    }    
]
```

How can I get json object value based on two key data? 
for instance, my psy_num is 3 and age are 25 then it will get Result data to be shown. Results data should depend on two psy_num and age. If the user has psy_num and age is matched it will show results data to the users.

Previously I used

I calculate age from date of birth of users to know age. I also get psy_num which is sum of day(2+1=3) from date of birth.

```
let flowData = JSON.parse(body);

function getResults(key, flowData) {
    var i, len = flowData.length;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (FlowData[i] && flowData[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            return flowData[i][key];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
console.log(getResults('psy_num', flowData.flows));`
```

## This is actual JSON File

https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=lqIrhrynJpI_9UZ7nxCi02IC6PJmilqVpAZu5qIH-NHKjJQsnpuxQvcXAwEYtPVGo7WUG4zt8U4X7Rrd4r7eGFNJdS71X83pOJmA1Yb3SEsKFZqtv3DaNYcMrmhZHmUMWojr9NvTBuBLhyHCd5hHa1ZsYSbt7G4nMhEEDL32U4DxjO7V7yvmJPXJTBuCiTGh3rUPjpYM_V0PJJG7TIaKp0gzTkmNhWNdTTY0t4K_dLqFVQC0BmEoHh1iraj-hUoovHjOg3Oej01Fd1uEZR7p_DU9HkkyTh_9SkCMY51DGu3m4vHBGULOCg&lib=MbpKbbfePtAVndrs259dhPT7ROjQYJ8yx

Comment: What did you try? and where you are failing?

Comment: You're using JSON, but you're struggling with a loop containing an if and two equality checks? Start from the basics.

Comment: Just to note: That isn't the JSON you're getting. Or if it is, it's invalid JSON. We can't help you if we don't know what the actual data looks like. (Not **all** of it, but we need to see the actual structure.)

Comment: @RajuSharma previously I used

I calculate age from date of birth of users to know age. I also get psy_num which is sum of day(2+1=3) from date of birth.

let flowData = JSON.parse(body);

`function getResults(key, flowData) {
    var i, len = flowData.length;
    
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (FlowData[i] && flowData[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            return flowData[i][key];
        }
    }
    
    return -1;
}

console.log(getResults('psy_num', flowData.flows));`

Comment: So your question isn't even about Java, but about JavaScript. Jeez, you don't know the name of the language you're using?

Comment: @JBNizet Yes I am using Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search in array you can use `filter()` function:

```
flowData.filter(arrayItem => {
    // here is condition
    return arrayItem.psy_num = your_psy_value && arrayItem. Age = your_age_value;
})
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  But need  results value based on psy_num value  and age value

Comment: @BaniNaveen, and why this answer is not based on based on psy_num value and age value?

Comment: I mean how to get Results value if my psy_num value is 3 and age value is 25

Comment: @BaniNaveen, isn't it what `filter()` return?

Comment: can u tell me how to access results content

Comment: @BaniNaveen, assign this code to some variable `var result = flowData.filter()`